# android: multi autocomplete textview dropdown item with image

Tags: image, autocomplete, favorites

I've implemented MultiAutoComplete powered by a String taken from database everything works fine. Now i'm trying to add a 'favorites' feature to my app, so when i set an item to favorite, the dropdown from autocomplete will display an image. I can display image to all items, but thats not what I want(display image to faved only).

guess i will just set visibility, but how to do that for one item?
Please help.
Thanks